# a simple editor

Tags: wysiwyg

i want to create a simple text editor for a website which works something like forums..
eg. if the user clicks on font color(after selecting a particular text), the selected text should be wrapped around some text something like 
[FONT COLOR="some_color"]sample text[/FONT]

i don't wanna use tinymce, because it's mammoth for my needs..any suggestions??
thankx..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made something similar, but without BBCode implementation, http://project.james-brooks.net/LivePreview/

Answer (score 2):

Nicedit will do for you I think :)

Two interesting reviews on RTE's:

http://blog.webdistortion.com/2008/03/09/9-of-the-best-rich-text-editors-reviewed/
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/